# PIC18F24J10 activating second UART pins with Remapping in CCS

Tags: microcontroller, uart, cpu-registers, pic, modbus-rtu-over-tcp

I have a problem that remapping second uart pin from PIC18F24J10 in CCS. I write this code for configurate after that configuration occures this error how do I have to do for fixing it. I am new at PIC programing.

I applied as in many MPLAB examples to CCS code couldn find anything for CCS  example everyone does MPLAB .But I didn't come across the ccs example

Comment: If you want help, you had to share your code.

Comment: _**I write this code for configurate after that configuration occures this error**_ So where is the code? Where is the error message?